# Unique Set of an ordered key value pairs where the keys are only valid keys of another type

Tags: typescript

I'd like to create a type that takes a set (an array of key/value pairs with non-repeating keys).

```js
// I have any given interface:
interface PersonRecord {
  id: string
  name: string
  age: number
}

// A type for order by direction
type SortDirection = "asc" | "desc"
```

I'd like to have some type/interface combination that would allow me to do something like this:

**valid objects:**

```js
const orderSort: SortType<PersonRecord> = {
  0: { id: "asc" }
  1: { age: "desc" }
}

const personNameSort: SortType<PersonRecord> = {
  0: { name: "desc" }
}
```

**invalid objects:**

```js
// only one key from PersonRecord at a time can be used in
// the values of the top level keys
const orderSort: SortType<PersonRecord> = {
  0: { id: "asc", age: "desc" }
}

// The top level keys must be numbers starting at zero and iterating
// every natural number by having no skips
const orderSort: SortType<PersonRecord> = {
  0: { id: "asc" }
  2: { age: "desc" }
}

// "xxx" is not a valid value because its not "asc" or "desc"
const personNameSort: SortType<PersonRecord> = {
  0: { name: "xxx" }
}

// test is not a key on PersonRecord
const personNameSort: SortType<PersonRecord> = {
  0: { test: "xxx" }
}

// keys from PersonRecord can only be used once
const orderSort: SortType<PersonRecord> = {
  0: { id: "asc" }
  1: { id: "desc" }
}
```

Here's an attempt at getting part of this piece working.

```js
type SortType<T> = { [K in keyof Partial<T>]: SortDirection }
```

Some alternative solutions I'll accept:
An array of key/value (value restricted to "asc" or "desc") and the keys cannot be reused:

```js
// this would work...
const sortOrder = [{name: "asc"},{age: "desc"}]

// ...but this wouldn't because age was already included in the array.
// If there's not a clean way of adding this restriction, then I can
// write code to prevent this restriction programmatically I'm sure.
const sortOrder = [{name: "asc"},{age: "desc"},{age: "asc"}]
```

**EDIT:**
So to help with this solution, let me explain exactly what this would be used for.

I want to make a function like this:

```js
// orderArgs could be an array also so maybe something like
// SortType<T>[] and each item in the array is just something like:
// [{someAttribute: "asc"},{anotherAttribute: "desc"}]
// and you can only have an array of ONE key/value pair.
const orderBy = (orderArgs: SortType<T>) => {
  // a variable that orderBy has access to is called
  // 'records' which is of type: T[]
  return records.sort((last, next) => {
    // to determine which value to return (-1, 0 or 1)
    // I want to sort against the first item in orderArgs
    // if they are not equal, return 1 or -1.
    // However, if they are equal, go to the next item in
    // orderArgs and try sort based on that.
    // If you've gone through the whole list of orderArgs,
    // then last and next are truly equal, so return 0 here.
  }
}
```

**EDIT 2**:
Here's a codesandbox proof of concept using @jcalz tips/help:

https://codesandbox.io/s/typed-data-storage-example-7n3kk4?file=/src/lib/useDataTable.ts

Comment: For `SortType<T>`, is there any practical limit to how big `keyof T` is, and how many of those keys people are likely to sort by?  You could write `SortType<T>` as a union of all possible acceptable values but this hits combinatorial explosion pretty quickly.  Your examples are all showing things on the order of three, which is fine.  But seven would be pushing it, and ten would be impossible.

Comment: Like, [this](https://tsplay.dev/mMM76m) is one way to proceed, but oof, if you have 7 keys it takes forever to even calculate the huge union type you need.  You could make a generic helper function that *checks* a value without having a specific *type* for it.  Would that be acceptable?

Comment: That approach looks like [this code](https://tsplay.dev/wRR7xw).  If you can show the use case of your original `SortType<T>` formulation, I could show to refactor to use this version.  The idea is that whatever currently wants `SortType<T>` would have to have an extra generic type parameter.

Comment: @jcalz re: 1st comment. Great question. No there is no limit so combinations could be a problem. I've discovered a new cool tool (TS Playground) Thanks for that. I'll have to book mark that. I see what you're trying to do with the combinations but my intuition says there is probably a cleaner solution to this. I might even consider creating a class that allows me to create an ordered list of columns to sort by.

Comment: @jcalz check out my edit. This is the bottom line for what I'm really trying to do. Id like to use Typescript to make sure that sorts are only "asc" (ascending) or "desc" (descending) and that the order attributes should only be keys based on the Type (`PersonRecord` for example) because it doesnt make sense to try to access `last[key]` or `next[key]` if `key` doesn't exist on those objects.

Comment: In that last edit, is `T` a specific type or something? Seems like it should be a type parameter, but I don't see it being declared anywhere.  I see you haven't implemented that sort function either.  Is `sortBy()` a method on a class known to contain a list of `T`s in it, like [this maybe](https://tsplay.dev/NBkQnm)?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Its not a Typed class but its a custom React Hook that I created that lets me store typed objects into local storage. Your solution is basically what I'm looking for I believe. If you post it as an answer, I'll upvote it and the if I need corrections, I'll comment or edit the post and then mark is a the accepted answer. Sorry it took me a few days, I've been busy.

Comment: @jcalz check out the latest edit. I applied some of what you did to my hook. It would be nice to be able to call `orderBy` without having to pass any types to it. Take a look and see what you can do. Thanks for the help btw, I'm still learning Typescript.

Comment: Also, take not of the comments I've added to the `useDataTable.ts` file when I've added your type definitions to my file.